# Giving the dropdown menu in the navbar 100% width of the screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The navbar in my app is very small so it doesn't collapse until 300px. One of the items in navbar is the notification counter, that when clicked on, displays recent notifications in a dropdown menu. I would like to make this dropdown menu take 100% of the width of the screen on xs screens (max-width:768px) but writing media queries and setting the width to 100% doesn't work since the dropdown menu is bounded by it's parent which has a small width. It would also be nice to make it look the collapsed navbar (dark background and all) but that's not important. I would appreciate any comments to helo me achieve this.

Comment: What's the current situation? Can you post a code snippet or a fiddle or even a snapshot?

Comment: Do you think it's possible to have a dropdown menu take 100% screen width without using javascript?

Comment: for people who may find this later: search yamm